# How does erc725, erc735 deter identity fraud?

Tags: erc725, erc735

Specifically, How does erc725, erc735 deter identity fraud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ERC725](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/725) and [ERC735](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/735) describe contracts in which the owner can store various "claims" (email ownership, mailing address, permissions, etc.).

These claims are typically verified by a trusted third party. Check out [this article](https://medium.com/originprotocol/managing-identity-with-a-ui-for-erc-725-5c7422b38c09) for some examples. The third party could be trusted DApp like AirBnB that provides email validation as a requirement for any transactions. Or the third party could be a DApp for address verification owned by the US Post Office. Etc.

Hopefully this sort of verification would greatly inhibit identity theft.